# Displaying many-to-many groupings in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ef-code-first

I'm not sure if i'm on the right track with this one, but essentially I'm trying to display a grouped list of items, where each item can be a member of multiple groups. i.e. The two entities are related on a many-to-many basis. I'll try to explain...

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

My question is, how do I group items like this into a control? I'm aware of the ICollectionView and the PropertyGroupDescription, but that doesn't seem to serve my purpose here (it seems to only work in a one-to-many scenario).

Any ideas?

Some points to note:

1. When displayed in a list, I want to show all Component's grouped by Kit.
2. When I select a component from this list, I only want **that** particular instance of the Component (i.e. I want Component + the Kit I selected it from).
3. Ignore the fact that i'm using a TreeView to show the items below, as i'll actually be using a ListBox with a GroupStyle
4. I'm using code-first EF 4.3.1 and the WPF MVVM pattern.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a treeview - are you having a problem getting the data into the treeview?  Or into your grouped list?  I'm unclear on what the actual problem is - are you not sure how to create a hierarchical DataTemplate?  Your point #2 alludes to a specific problem that I've seen before - is there a particular problem you're having around selection?

Comment: I think what i'm asking is 2 different questions. Firstly, I want to pull all components from the database (of which there could be multiple instances of the same component i.e. Tank -> Glue and Gunship -> Glue), as one flat list.
Secondly, I want to display them in a ListBox, grouping them by Kit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Include() method on the context object to include the related entities.

Comment: Thanks, I think that solves the problem of getting multiple instances of Component, but I still need to find a way of grouping it in the UI.